# Mit oder ohne »es«?

Tags: word-usage, pronoun, expletiva

Gestern habe ich eine Diskussion gehabt, ob man das Pronomen *es* in folgendem Satz verwendet oder nicht:

> Im Vertrag wird [es] stehen, dass ...

Wahrscheinlich wird kein Deutscher *es* in dem Satz verwenden, weil es falsch klingt; es konnte mir aber auch keiner erklären warum.

Ich habe zwar im Internet gefunden, dass die Verwendung von *es* optional wäre, aber das haben meine Freunde nicht akzeptiert.

Habt ihr eine Erklärung?

Comment: Deutsche würden das `es` verwenden, wenn sie es inhaltlich betonen möchten.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wäre die Satzstellung anders und *es* stünde an erster Stelle, wäre es ein sogenanntes [Expletivum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum), welches die Rolle eines Subjekts übernimmt, das vom Satzbau benötigt wird, aber nicht vorhanden ist:

> »Es wird im Vertrag stehen, dass …«

In diesem Fall darf *es* nicht weggelassen werden, da sonst das Verb *wird* an erster Stelle stünde und deswegen die Syntax unzulässig wäre.

In Deinem Beispielsatz tritt dieses Problem nicht auf, da *im Vertrag* an erster Stelle steht – *es* kann also weggelassen werden. Dass der Nebensatz als Subjekt fungiert, stellt kein Problem dar und dieser kann sogar an die erste Stelle gerückt werden – so wie in diesem Satz hier. Beachte, dass eine Umstellung des Satzes die inhaltliche Betonung ändern kann.

Wird *es* im Beispielsatz trotzdem verwendet, ist es kein Expletivum mehr, sondern ein reguläres Pronomen, das für den Nebensatz steht ([Korrelat](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum)) und diesen betont (da es sonst unnötig ist), z. B.:

> »Wir haben nicht über … gesprochen.« – »Keine Sorge: Im Vertrag wird **es** stehen, dass …«

Ich würde empfehlen, ein *es* in dieser Position nur zu diesem Zweck einzusetzen, da es sonst missverstanden werden kann bzw. seltsam bis falsch wirkt.

Beachte außerdem, dass es Verben gibt, die ein Expletivum unabhängig vom Satzbau fordern (z. B. *regnen:* »Gestern regnete es.«) oder bei denen ein *es* auch als drittes oder späteres Satzglied normal ist und nicht betonend wirkt, obwohl optional (z. B. *gefallen:* »Mir gefällt es, dass …« Das *es* ist optional, wirkt aber nicht betonend).

Comment: D.h. die Variante mit "es" ist nicht falsch und es klingt für die meisten Deutsche falsch? Oder doch falsch?

Comment: Die Variante mit *es* ist nicht falsch, klingt aber zumindest seltsam. (Es sei denn, es gibt einen Anlass, den Nebensatz zu betonen.)

Comment: Es meiner Meinung nach ein Problem mit der Argumentation... das "es" in Drittstellung ist NICHT dasselbe "es" wie das Expletivum in Erststellung sondern ein "echtes" Subjekt. Das kann man überprüfen indem man einen Plural ansetzt.
"In dem Vertrag werden stehen Rechte, Pflichten und weitere Konditionen." vs. "Es werden in dem Vertrag Rechte, Pflichten usw..." Das "es" an erster Stelle hat KEINEN Einfluss auf das Verb, das an dritter hingegen schon. Sie sind also nicht dasselbe...

Comment: Ich finde weiterhin, dass das drittgestellte "es" extrem merkwürdig, wenn nicht sogar falsch klingt. Allerdings gibt es andere Verben, bei denen es normal ist... "Mir gefällt es nicht, dass du nie abwäschst"

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich kann Dein Argument nicht ganz nachvollziehen, da der Satz im Plural mit *es* an dritter Stelle und eigentlichem Subjekt (Rechte, …) nicht existiert. Nichtsdestotrotz zweifele ich auch an der Klassifizierung des *es* in Drittstellung als Expletivum, da ein Expletivum ja nicht ausgelassen werden könnte. Ich würde dazu tendieren *es* in Erststellung als Expletivum und in Drittstellung als normales Pronomen zu klassifizieren, was dann auch den Bedeutungsunterschied fassen würde. So oder so ändert die Frage der Schublade nichts an den Schlussfolgerungen.

Comment: Ich habe einige der Anmerkungen in die Antwort eingearbeitet.

Comment: Das _es_ ist hier ein [Korrelat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korrelat_%28Grammatik%29).

Comment: @chirlu: In dritter Position ja, in erster Position scheiden sich darüber anscheinend die Geister und zumindest eine [Quelle](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/faecher/germanis/daf/neu/materialien/gr-repet/satz/0301Expletes.php) stuft es nicht als Korrelat ein. Ich würde mich dem anschließen, da nach mein Sprachgefühl das *es* in Erstposition nicht für den Nebensatz steht.