# Leaving out "es" in clause with reflexive verb

Tags: grammar, expletiva

> Als sich abzeichnete, dass die Zahl der Asylbewerber in diesem Jahr auf mehr als 100 000 steigen würde, ...

Is *Als sich abzeichnete* the same as *Als es sich abzeichnete?* Is it typical to leave out *es* in this reflexive-verb construction? (I guess we can’t say *Als schien* instead of *Als es schien.)*

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my guess. Just for sake of keep tracking of the elements of the sentence,suppose you don't have `Als` but `Denn`, which is a "position zero particle", that is, you could omit it without grammatically make a mistake (although, of course, the meaning of the sentence wouldn't be the same)

> Denn es zeichnete sich ab, dass ...

and

> Es zeichnete sich ab, dass ...

The point is that you need **es** here, in order for the verb to be in position two, as it should. Then `es` is said to be a *Platzhalter*. Compare

> - Sich damit zu beschäftigen ist hier kaum möglich *and*
> - Es ist kaum möglich,  damit hier sich zu beschäftigen.

Now,  `als` doesn't work as a "position zero" particle, because one says

> Als du gekommen bist, ....

but if one leaves `als` out, the sentence must be modified

> Du bist gekommen

Then `als` is taking a place and you no longer need `es`.