# Mit oder ohne “es”, wenn man einen Nebensatz einleiten will

Tags: grammar

Laut der akzeptierten Antwort auf [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/mit-oder-ohne-es) sollte man lieber "Im Vertrag wird stehen, dass..." als "Im Vertrag wird *es* stehen, dass..." sagen. Ich bin aber vor kurzem auf das Folgende gestoßen:

> Facebook ermöglicht **es** dir, mit den Menschen in deinem Leben in Verbindung zu treten und Inhalte mit diesen zu teilen.

---

Meine Frage ist:

Klingt es

> Facebook ermöglicht dir, mit den Menschen in deinem Leben in Verbindung zu treten und Inhalte mit diesen zu teilen.

nicht besser? und warum genau denkt Ihr, dass Facebook es so geschrieben hat? Klingt es vielleicht mit "es" ein bisschen formeller?

Comment: Hinweis: Facebook wird von Nutzern mitübersetzt. Das läuft erst über Übersetzungsvorschläge und anschließend mit einem Voting. Leider sind viele Vorschläge bereits von Beginn ziemlich schlecht, sodass beim Voting eine Auswahl der „richtigen” Übersetzung gar nicht möglich ist. Das sorgt dann für die schwankende Qualität und Inkonsistenz der Übersetzungen dort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sowohl

> Facebook ermöglicht es dir, (…)

als auch

> Facebook ermöglicht dir, (…)

sind stilistisch in Ordnung. Ich persönlich würde Letzteres bevorzugen. In diesem Fall steht das "es" übrigens im Akkusativ. Im Satz "Im Vertrag wird es stehen, dass …" steht es im Nominativ. Dieser Satz klingt nur wegen der Wortstellung seltsam. "Es wird im Vertrag stehen, dass …" wäre hier üblich und auch mit "es" gebräuchlich.

Answer (score 1):

Ist das im englischen Original "Facebook allows you to..."? Man könnte sowas auch als "Mit Facebook kannst Du / kann man..." übersetzen.

Answer (score 1):

Als kleine Ergänzung ist *es* in diesem Fall nur fakultativ, wenn der Nebensatz bzw. die Infinitivkonstruktion nach dem Hauptsatz steht.

Das *es* hier nicht weg zu lassen, wäre nicht in Ordnung:

> Mit (…) zu teilen, ermöglicht e̶s̶ dir fb.

Stattdessen könnte *es* durch *das* ersetz werden:

> Mit (…) zu teilen, das ermöglicht dir fb.